# How can I improve my Product Export time duration for Bulk export

Tags: magento-1.9, bug

In my store approximately 16,000 products are there. When I try to export both ways import/export or dataflow, both show error. But when I export less amount of data (say 200-300 products at a time), I am able to export my products. Which means I can't able to export all my products at a single file.

*System > Import/Export > Export* error:

[image: Export error]

*System > Import/Export > Dataflow profiles > Export all products* error:

[image: Export all products error]

Comment: export them in batches.

Comment: could you please explain briefly.

Comment: I don't know exact error, let me know one thing clear, my export working in localhost perfectly,  after i host only i got the export error, the matter of the error is, my export working, bulk export only not working, is there any memory allocation error or my host provider error or my file copy  error, help me to get out from this killer head ache.

Comment: How can i export like batches.

Comment: apply filters to the export

Comment: but what about my not filters product,

Comment: Actually may i know the error sir, the solution is second part, atleast i want know my error.

Comment: @Marius : Shall i post as a bug to magento

Comment: Please stop asking the same question again and again with different words, you are wasting the time of everybody who tries to help you and does not see that the same advice has been given before. You can add information to the original question and/or add a bounty to draw attention to it.

Answer (score 0):

For your requirement, you need to increase php memory limit. You can do this using [this link](http://magentoexpertforum.com/showthread.php/10322-Increase-PHP-memory-limit):

> There are many ways to change PHP memory limit. These are very simple
>   ways to do
>
> 1. php.ini
>
> Locate your php.ini file by run phpinfo() function, I think you must
>   have PHP skill enough to do this .
>
> Then find out the line like this in php.ini file
>
> Code:
>
> `memory_limit = 64M`
>
> You can change 64M to whatever you want.
>
> This way only do when you are owner of server or VPS. Let 's use other
>   way if you are not.
>
> 2. .htaccess
>
> Put this line in your first line of your .htaccess file
>
> Code:
>
> `php_value memory_limit 64M`

After increasing memory limit, try to export using dataprofile.

Comment: is this ok ....

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/odFBDut.png

Comment: Magento comes with a default .htaccess file in the root directory that includes this configuration directive.
  - php_value memory_limit 64M
  - php_value max_execution_time 18000
You can simply change this value from 64MB to 96M or 128MB depending on your needs. This value should be kept to the minimum necessary to run your application.

Comment: is this ok,....

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/7fEht9D.png

Comment: still not clear the problem,,

Comment: Try caching, indexing and than import again.

Comment: I did try this one actually,

Comment: I don't know exact error, let me know one thing clear, my export working in localhost perfectly, after i host only i got the export error, the matter of the error is, my export working, bulk export only not working, is there any memory allocation error or my host provider error or my file copy error

Comment: Contact your hosting provider for this error, and let him know about memory limit increased by us manually, they will look into this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42867/discussion-between-jeeva-rathinam-and-magecomp).

Comment: Am already spoke with them, Godaddy is my hosting provider actually,  they can't help and don't know about this error

Comment: Can i get any other magento help,

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42904/discussion-between-jeeva-rathinam-and-magecomp).